# Unique title for sapply when using rasters

Tags: r, plot, raster

I am running a random forest model, predicting on a new dataset and then breaking the prediction into 20 year periods, turning this into a raster and mapping each time period.  The below code works great except that I can't get the title of each plot to be unique.  I tried creating a list and calling names or colnames, but so far nothing has worked.  As is it prints each map with all 3 titles above.

[image]

If i try to something like Rasts[l] I get --  Error in Rasts[l] : invalid subscript type 'S4'

My guess is because because this is a raster it is not behaving like a typical dataframe would because none of the potential solutions I've found have worked.

```
#subsets by year
sp1960 <- predict_all[predict_all$year>1960  &predict_all$year<1980,]
sp1980 <- predict_all[predict_all$year>=1980 &predict_all$year<2000,]
sp2000 <- predict_all[predict_all$year>=2000 &predict_all$year<2020,]

#turn the data into a raster
library(plotKML)
library(RColorBrewer)

Rasts <- list("A"=sp1960,"B"=sp1980,"C"=sp2000)
title_list <- list("A", "B", "C")

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
sapply(Rasts, function(l) {
new_rasts<-raster(vect2rast(l, fname = names(l)[2], cell.size=.05))
pal <- brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "PuBu")
scale_range <- c(0, 1)
title <-paste("RF:",title_list,sp_name)
plot(new_rasts, col=pal,zlim=scale_range, main=title)
plot(wrld_simpl, add=TRUE, border='dark grey')
})
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Val Completely agree.  I'm not sure how to provide something reproducible since I'm working with spatial data frames

Comment: You can always create a spatial dataframe with the same characteristics of your data just with random values ... or if the size permits, you can use `dput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem appears to be, in your original sample code you are pasting the entire list of titles in `title_list` into `title` of every graph.

It's not possible to test without you having included a minimal reproducible example.

However, taking a stab at it you might try modifying your `sapply` statement to run over the index to the `Rasts` list. By using an index for the sapply loop, you can reference e.g. `Rasts[i]` and `title_list[i]` by the index number and match them as you go.

For example, I think you would need to modify your sapply call to be something like:

```
sapply(seq_along(Rasts), function(i) {
  new_rasts<-raster(vect2rast(Rasts[i], fname = names(Rasts[i])[2], cell.size=.05))
  pal <- brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "PuBu")
  scale_range <- c(0, 1)
  title <-paste("RF:",title_list[i],sp_name)
  plot(new_rasts, col=pal,zlim=scale_range, main=title)
  plot(wrld_simpl, add=TRUE, border='dark grey')
})
```

Above, (as you havn't defined it anywhere in your OP) I'm guessing from your sample output that `sp_name` is a character constant (i.e. for lack of other information it appears as the same text in all your graph title outputs).

If however `sp_name` is a list, simply please replace it in the function with `sp_name[i]` to loop within the sapply along with the other parallel lists. Same if `wrld_simpl` is a list, replace it in the function with `wrld_simpl[i]`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly with only one small change i had to use Rasts[[i]] in double brackets.  No idea why but this is how each spatial data frame appeared in the Rasts list.  For anyone else -- With only one bracket I received the error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘vect2rast’ for signature ‘"list"’